# How to find singular matrix eigenvector?

Tags: r, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have a 800x800 singular (covariance) matrix and I want to find it's largest eigenvalue and eigenvector corresponding to this eigenvalue.
Does anybody know wheter it is possible to do it with R?

Comment: see `eigen` function (e.g. `result$values[1]` and `result$vectors[,1]`)

Comment: @Marcinthebox, it's not working for singular matrix

Comment: Ok, jumped the gun I guess. You may want to provide a small example. perhaps `svd` would find a solution where `eigen` does not.

Comment: @Marcinthebox, can't find how to use swd for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using `svd` for the decomposition of a covariance matrix:

```
a <- matrix(runif(16),4)
C <- cov(a)
res <- svd(C)
res
res$d[1] # largest singular value
res$u[,1] # largest vector ; u and v are the same
```

Hope that helps.